# How do I get a single parameter from a list of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have model that contains a collection of child objects called: Model.TagsExisting
I want to get the TagName parameter from all the `TagsExisting` objects without doing a lousy loop as such:

```
List<string> tagList = new List<string>();
foreach(Tag t in Model.TagsExisting)
{
    tagList.Add(t.TagName);
}
```

Is there a cleaner LINQ way?... thought I saw one before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` that column and use `ToList` to get a `List<T>` back like:

```
List<string> tagList = Model.TagsExisting
                            .Select(t=> t.TagName)
                            .ToList();
```

or with a query syntax:

```
List<string> tagList = (from t in Model.TagsExisting
                       select t.TagName).ToList();
```

Comment: @Beau, what you actually want ? a single value from `TagName` or List of TagNames as your original code in the question

Comment: If you need a single item then use `First/FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList` It is not really clear what you want

Comment: My fault. It's working. I was confusing myself between two issues.

Comment: If you are using First/FirstOrDefault you may also want to order the data to ensure you get the right return (latest item for example)    .OrderByDescending(x => x.<Field>)